# Как организовать цикл на языке С# для данной задачи

Tags: c#, матрицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как написать цикл, чтоб каждый элемент матрицы считался по данному условию? например в первом столбце будет приравнено номеру строки, а во втором столбце k=j-1, то есть будет равен номеру строки, ну а в следующих столбцах считается по сумме. Логику задачи я понял, а вот как код написать, помогите пожалуйста

в языке c# я не особо шарю, на pascal написал, а как на C# не шарю:

```
for i:=1 to n do 
for j:=1 to n do 
begin 
if j=1 then a[i,j]:=1 
else 
begin 
a[i,j]:=0; 
for k:=1 to j-1 do 
a[i,j]:=a[i,j]+a[i,k]; 
end; 
end;
```

Comment: Ну с циклом for Вы знакомы?

Comment: @Valerka, добавьте, пожалуйста, код в сам вопрос и отформатируйте его. Это -- раз. Раз Вы можете написать на Паскале, то сможете и на C#, хотя бы, попробуйте. Единственная по большому счету разница в том, что в C# массивы индексируются, начиная с нуля. Если не получится, если будут вопросы -- велкам, но не раньше, кмк. Здесь можно почитать про массивы: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/arrays, Здесь про циклы: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for

Comment: хорошо, сейчас займусь этим